# if number is a decimal between 2 numbers (php)

Tags: php, numbers, decimal

I'm writings a PHP script that calculates an average of a number.

EXAMPLE:

```
$rating = 7;
$votes = 3;

$AvgRating = number_format($rating / $votes,1);
```

The return `$AvgRating` for this would be 2.3 (to 1 decimal place).

is it possible to say.....

```
if ($AvgRating > 2 && $AvgRating < 3){   
   $display = 'between';
}
echo $display;
```

I have tried but it does not work, I have tried google but don't know exactly what I need to look for.

Comment: possible to say "what"?

Comment: sorry first time posting, i have edited the post

Comment: wait..what are you trying to do,are you trying to do an if statement for $AvgRating or for $rating?Cos one is a non decimal number and one isn't...

Comment: my appologies an if statement on the $AvgRating

Comment: if ($AvgRating > 7 && $AvgRating < 8.0){
...
}

Comment: When you say that $AvgRating should return 7.3 do you actually mean 2.3 ? Cause that's what you're calculating there with $rating / $votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there is some mistakes $AvgRating retunrs 2.3 not 7.3

So you have to check with this

```
$rating =7; $votes=3;

$AvgRating = number_format($rating / $votes,1);

if ($AvgRating > 2 && $AvgRating < 3.0){

   echo $AvgRating; 
}
```

Comment: thanks pugazhenthi, you get what i am trying to do, sorry having a brain drain.....


$AvgRatings = number_format(2.3,1);
if ($rating > 2 && $rating < 3){   
    $display = 'between';
 }
 echo $display;

i have tried this, but i am not getting any display

Comment: HI please check your variable it is not $rating. I think correct variable is $AvgRatings..

Comment: thanks for your pacience, i have edited the original post to the correct code now, i have been messing my brain up for hours with this and had the answer the whole time! i am so sorry to waste your times! thanks all....... *NOTE TO SELF, DONT WORK TILL GONE 4:33am*

Answer (score 1):

This code evaluates correctly...

```
<?php
    $rating = 7;
    $votes = 3;

    $AvgRating = number_format($rating / $votes,1); 

    if ($AvgRating > 2 && $AvgRating < 3){   
       $display = 'between';
    }
    echo $display;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is whether the condition inside the if statement is correct, yes it is.

However in your case, the if condition fails since the value of `$AvgRating` (7/3) is less than 7. So you probably might be checking whether `$AvgRating` is greater than 2.